# Laravel 7.14 when condition not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to create filters using where and wherebetween. If the user doest not enter the value in whereBetween it should not be in url.

Here's my Controller:

```
 $prod = $request->input('productfm');
    $sub = $request->input('sub-family');
    $location = $request->input('location');

    $thickness = [$request->input('minthick'), $request->input('maxthick')];

    $width = [$request->input('minwidth'), $request->input('maxwidth')];

    $weight = [$request->input('minweight'), $request->input('maxweight')];

    // dd($prod);

    $products = Product::where('state_id', '=', '1')
                    ->when(!empty($prod), function ($query) use ($prod) {
                        return $query->where('product_family', $prod);
                    })
                    ->when(!empty($sub), function ($query) use ($sub) {
                        return $query->where('sub_family', $sub);
                    })
                    ->when(!empty($location), function ($query) use ($location) {
                        return $query->where('location', $location);
                    })
                    ->when(!empty($thickness), function ($query) use ($thickness) {
                        return $query->whereBetween('thick', $thickness);
                    })
                    ->when(!empty($width), function ($query) use ($width) {
                        return $query->whereBetween('width', $width);
                    })
                    ->when(!empty($weight), function ($query) use ($weight) {
                        return $query->whereBetween('weight', $weight);
                    })
                    ->get();
```

All fields are a select input in form. If I keep $prod, $sub_family and $location it works. But it's not working in whereBetween range filter.

URL still shows empty input of range filters and results don't come-up.

How do I make it clean/dynamic url? On dd($product) it returns empty array.

Comment: Still array `$thickness = [$request->input('minthick'), $request->input('maxthick')];` @OMR

Comment: `->when(!empty($prod), function ($query, $prod){return $query->where('product_family', $prod);  })` Use that for each when @Nargesh Rana

Comment: I just want to understand why url is not clean if user does not enter whereBetween values.

Comment: Hi Nargresh, I think you are not understanding how empty works, an array will only return empty if it has no values, if you pass [null, null] or ['', ''] to empty it will return false as it has values in the array even if they are null or even blank.  So you need to change your logic for this.